# Error when calling a component react native

Tags: react-native

I want to create a component like this to check if the user idle or not.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {View, PanResponder, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const ScreenConponent = ({...props}) => {
  console.tron.log(props);
  const timerId = useRef(false);
  const [timeForInactivityInSecond, setTimeForInactivityInSecond] =
    useState(3600);

  useEffect(() => {
    resetInactivityTimeout();
  }, []);

  const panResponder = React.useRef(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => {
        console.tron.log('user starts touch');
        resetInactivityTimeout();
      },
    }),
  ).current;

  const resetInactivityTimeout = () => {
    clearTimeout(timerId.current);
    timerId.current = setTimeout(() => {
      console.tron.log('user idle');
    }, timeForInactivityInSecond * 1000);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} {...panResponder.panHandlers}>
      {props.children}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default ScreenConponent;
```

and this is how i call the component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

import Screen from '../../components/Screen';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Screen>
      <View> <Text> Test </Text> </View>
    </Screen>
  );
}
```

But when i tried to call the component, i got an error like this [error when run the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY6DK.png)

anyone have an idea what's wrong with the code? because i can use this method in react (web)

this is the navigation code

```
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
// import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';

import ScheduleScreen from '../pages/Schedule';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

/** Main route */
const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Schedule"
        component={ScheduleScreen}
        options={{
          header: () => null,
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const Root = createStackNavigator();

const RootNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Root.Navigator>
        <Root.Screen
          name="Main"
          component={MainNavigator}
          options={{header: () => null}}
        />
      </Root.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default RootNavigator;
```

Comment: Are you using navigation somewhere else in your app? That err doesn't look related to this page.

Comment: Is the nav state context tsx.file mentioned in the error something you wrote?

Comment: yeah i'm using reactnavigation.. What i don't understand is why the error related to reactnavigation?

Comment: I don't think the above files are causing the issue. It seems that you have installed `react-navigation`, which requires you to wrap your navigator inside a `NavigationContainer`. Can you confirm that part is done?

Comment: I'm guessing it's somehow being loaded into your component tree higher than the component's you pasted above. You will have to paste your entire components trees code,.not just this leaf level part, in order to get assistance with that

Comment: @nithinpp i've added my navigation code

Comment: But if i call the component just like this <Screen />.. it works.. i've tried with a fresh app and still got the same error..

Comment: You have missed something on your MainNavigator component. You missed the <Stack.Navigator> opening tag before defining your screen.

Comment: Where are you rendering this `RootNavigator`?

Comment: Solved. I need to update my reactnavigation to the latest version.